# Excel VBA with ADODB connection produces text instead of values

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am currently using an ADODB connection to update some cells. The updating works fine (it updates the appropriate rows). However, when it pastes the values it appends an apostrophe (i.e. '5 instead of 5) which means it is unable to be formatted or added properly. I've tried using a replace but it can't find the apostrophe and I've tried using val() but no luck so far.

The code (simplified) looks as follows: All of the variables (sheet, tableAddressB etc.) are working fine, it's simply the '5' in this case that is not getting updated as a number.

```
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim tableAddressB As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"";"
    cn.Open

    tableAddressB = Sheet & "$" & Range(Sheet & "Details").Address(False, False)
    strSQL = "Update [" & tableAddressB & "] Set [" & tableAddressB & "].F5 = 5 " & _
             "Where [" & tableAddressB & "].F3 between #1/1/2016# and #3/1/2016#"

    cn.Execute strSQL
    cn.Close
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The data type of the columns is determined from the workbook before you do any update. Is there anything in `F5` before you do the update? Is there anything in the `F` column as a whole that's not a number? Try putting a dummy 0 there first.

Comment: I think you can just format the cell(s)? If it has this ' in front, it is formatted as text. http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/formatting-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Thanks both, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both Jeroen and Niclas. Putting a Range.NumberFormat and adjusting accordingly (Range.Numberformat = "0.00") works perfectly.

Thanks both for your help!